I don't know how to fix this NullReferenceException in C#
I'm programming a Text Adventure RPG in C# for a university project and it's due on Sunday. Now i've encountered this fatal exception that doesnt let me even execute the program.
class Program {
    public static Player currentPlayer = new("Giocatore");
    public static bool firstStart = true;
    public static bool roomBool1 = true;
    public static bool roomBool2 = true;


    public static Room? room0 = new() {
        Name = "Entrata",
        Description = "Sei in una stanza buia. Trovi solo una porta dimenandoti a nord.",
        NorthRoom = null,
        SouthRoom = null,
        EastRoom = null,
        WestRoom = null,
        Items = new List<Item>(),
        NPCs = new List<NPC>(),
        Enemies = new List<Enemy>()
    };
    public static Room? room1 = new() {
        Name = "Corridoio",
        NorthRoom = null,
        SouthRoom = room0,
        EastRoom = null,
        WestRoom = null,
        Items = new List<Item>(),
        NPCs = new List<NPC>(),
        Enemies = new List<Enemy>
            {
                new Enemy
                {
                    Name = "Re degli scheletri",
                    Description = "Imponente scheletro con una spada dorata e una corona arrugginita.",
                    Health = 500,
                    Attack = 50
                }
            },
        Description = $"Ti ritrovi in un corridoio illuminato da delle torce, con a sud la stanza in cui eri prima e in fondo\n {room1.Enemies[0].Name}, pronto ad attaccarti."
    };
    

    public static Room? currentRoom = room0;
    
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        currentPlayer.currentRoom = currentRoom;
        NewStart();
    }
}

The program gives the exception at "currentPlayer.currentRoom = room0;", but it also says that the issue is that room0 is null, but it doesnt look to me, and i dont know where the issue is. Also dont mind the strings in Italian.
public class Room {
    public string? Name {get; set;}
    public string? Description {get; set;}
    public Room? NorthRoom {get; set;}
    public Room? SouthRoom {get; set;}
    public Room? EastRoom {get; set;}
    public Room? WestRoom {get; set;}
    public List<Item>? Items {get; set;}
    public List<NPC>? NPCs {get; set;}
    public List<Enemy>? Enemies {get; set;}
}

The one above is the Room class.
public class Player : Personaggio {
    

    public Room currentRoom = Program.room0;
 
}

This one is the Player class, i removed all the irrelevant parts to the problem. If you can help me, thank you.
I tried to change the Room class in Room? when declaring the rooms, but it didnt work, just like not making them static, it didnt work. i also tried making them all in a List<Room>, but it didnt work at all, as expected. I really dont know how to fix this. I've already tried to look at other questions, but no one had my same issue, and every fix i've seen didn't work.

Check for racing conditions.

Stop using field initializer and intialize class members at constructor if you feel difficult to manage the order of the initialization.

Why do you have public Room? SouthRoom {get; set;} inside the Room class?

The following may be of interest: Debugger documentation - Visual Studio (Windows)
